# Bootstrap carousel example changing text margin and size with css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was hoping for some help with bootstrap's carousel specifically how to move the text in the  tags upward/vertically centered. The carousel has a left and right control and these are vertically centered relative to the carousel which has a height of 560px. However, the text which is contained in the  tags sits below the controls and I would also like this text vertically centered (or shifted upward)...I'm also struggling to adjust the font-size of the h1 tags so i'm guessing I'm not accessing the elements correctly from within my css file.

carousel.css

```
.carousel {
    height: 560px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.carousel-caption {
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel .item {
    height: 560px;
    background-color: #777;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 560px;
}
```

index.html

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img class="first-slide" src=...."/>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Text Here!!!!!!!!!!</h1>
                      <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Users")" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img class="second-slide" src=...."/>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                   <h1></h1>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">

            <div class="container">
                <img class="third-slide" src=....."/>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Text Here!!!!!</h1>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Take a peak at the CSS that vertically centers the controls and adapt that to the text.

Comment: You HTML structure is not correct

Comment: Further you are adding your `h1` inside `.caption` div of `carousel` you need to put it inside the container instead.

Comment: Thanks! But I looked at https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp and they have the h1 and p tags inside the carousel-caption. But I guess carousel-caption specifically puts it at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want the height of 560px, so while you run the code snippet, just scroll the section.

To put an element in center of the page, use the following css,

```
.text-center{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Try the below html and css, the text and button are in the center of the page.

```css
  <style>
  .carousel {
    height: 560px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.text-center{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.inner-center{
 width:100%;
}

.carousel-caption {
    z-index: 10;
    
}

.carousel .item {
    height: 560px;
    background-color: #777;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 560px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
           
                  <div class="text-center">
                   <div class="inner-center">
                      <h1>Sign up today</h1>
                      <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
                <div class="text-center">
                   <div class="inner-center">
                      <h1>Learn more</h1>
                      <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="text-center">
                   <div class="inner-center">
                      <h1>Browse</h1>
                      <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse</a></p>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel"  data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```